# Uploaded file sometimes doesn't appear on the Google Drive web page

Tags: google-drive-api

I've observed a strange behavior of Google Drive when I uploaded several files in a row to Google Drive by calling Google Drive APIs.

Everything seems working properly, I can get correct response back from API, such as file ID and URL. But when I looked into the folder where I uploaded files by web browser, files are sometimes missing.

This issue can be resolved by accessing the following URL which should not be necessary.

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/<file ID>/edit
```

Could it be a Google Drive bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Usually the file would appear after some time. But sometimes not at all! 
I've also noticed discrepancies between files shown in the web UI and files shown in the Google Drive directory on my PC. I would chalk this up to Drive's bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive still does this.

Files can take a long time to appear on the web gui. Similarly deleted files can remain on the web gui for a long time (and you get an error if you click on them).

I would really love a way to make drive more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

İf you are uploading your files inside a folder then this might cause a problem. Make sure that parent folder exists for the file that you upload.